# How to make errored inputs prepopulate with previously inputted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm making a custom AJAX form.

If a user fills out half of the form, it will fail wanting the other half fulfilled.

For some odd reason, the form is not pre-populating with at least what they had already inputted.

Because it's not doing this, how can I manually tell it to do so? When the form returns, the Object it verified is still accessible, so I can withdraw information from it.

**a sample of the form**

```
- form_for CardSignup.new do |f|
  - unless @card_signup.nil?
    -  if !@card_signup.errors.empty?
      .prefix_1.grid_4
        - @card_signup.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
          .warning
            = error
          %br/
  .grid_2.prefix_1{:style => "width: 166px;"}
    = f.text_field :first_name, :style => "width: 166px;", :value => "first name", :rel => "first name"
    %div{:class => 'error_message'}
```

**my Create method**

```
def create
  if params[:user] && current_user.admin
    @card_signup = User.find(params[:user]).build_card_signup(params[:card_signup])
  else
    @card_signup = current_user.build_card_signup(params[:card_signup])
  end
  if @card_signup.valid?
    respond_to do |wants|
      #wants.html { redirect_to disclaimer_card_signup_path, :locals => { :card_signup => @card_signup } }
      wants.json { render :json => { :html => (render_to_string :partial => 'disclaimer') } } 
    end
  else
    respond_to do |wants|
      #wants.html { redirect_to new_card_signup_path }
      wants.json { render :json => {:errors => @card_signup.errors, :html => (render_to_string :partial => '/card_signups/new_form') } }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
form_for CardSignup.new
```

which will instantiate a new CardSignup object every time you render the form. Move this into the **new action** and in the **create action** do this:

```
@card_signup = CardSignup.new(params[:card_signup])
```

This will pass the half-filled object back to the form and you'll get the already populated fields.

Comment: Ah, excellent point! I moved it to my controller and changed my form. And the form still passes appropriately, but still doesn't restore at least the parts of the object they *did* complete. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you responding from the controller? Are you passing back the entire object? Do you see the error messages?

Comment: In my console I can retrieve the errors, yes -- but the form is not failing. There are not syntactical errors. My controller I'm instantiating it as you mentioned in your example. I'll update the code above with my create method.